# fortran: count number of data in a line of a csv file

Tags: csv, fortran

I am tasked with Fortran program which count the number of integers in each line of a csv file. This file has a format below;

```
10,2,5,6,7,8
1,5,6,7
201,55,26,47,8,8,9,10
....
```

each line has different number of numbers. I need to count and rearrange in the format below

```
6 10 2 5 6 7 8
4 1 5 6 7
8 201 55 26 47 8 8 9 10
...
```

the first integer is number of integers in each line of the file. the following integers are the same as the line in the file. But commas should be removed. my first approach was to read entire line and proceed. But it seems difficult to handle unknown length of line.

```
character*5000 line
open(unit=5,file="new.csv",status="old",action="read")
read(unit=5,fmt="(A)") line
```

How can I count and rearrange this data in fortran

Thank you

Comment: Maybe take a look at http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/csv_io/csv_io.html

Comment: Don't use unit number `5` for your file access.  That unit number is usually pre-connected to `stdin` (or its equivalent on Windows and other operating systems) and, unless you know what you are doing, reconnecting it to another 'file' will make matters more complicated than they need be.  Use another number, perhaps `15`.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the formats are just as you say and  there are, e.g., no trailing commas or similar you might try something like

```
ian@ian-pc:~/test/csv$ cat new.csv
10,2,5,6,7,8
1,5,6,7
201,55,26,47,8,8,9,10
ian@ian-pc:~/test/csv$ cat csv.f90
Program csv

  Implicit None

  Character( Len = 5000 ) :: line

  Integer :: numnum
  Integer :: i

  Open( 10, file = 'new.csv' )

  Do
     Read( 10, '( a )', End = 200 ) line
     ! Work out how many numbers I've just eaten
     numnum = Count( (/ ( line( i:i ), i = 1, Len( line ) ) /) == ',' )
     numnum = numnum + 1
     ! Turn the commas into spaces adn work out where the original line ends
     Do i = 1, Len( line )
        If( line( i:i ) == ' ' ) Then
           Exit
        End If
        If( line( i:i ) == ',' ) Then
           line( i:i ) = ' ' 
        End If
     End Do
     Write( *, * ) numnum, line( 1:Min( Len( line ), i ) )
  End Do

200 Continue

End Program csv
ian@ian-pc:~/test/csv$ nagfor csv.f90
NAG Fortran Compiler Release 5.3.1(907)
[NAG Fortran Compiler normal termination]
ian@ian-pc:~/test/csv$ ./a.out
 6 10 2 5 6 7 8 
 4 1 5 6 7 
 8 201 55 26 47 8 8 9 10
```

But I have a feeling there may be something simpler ...

Comment: The only improvement I can think of is not counting the commas in an initial scan along `line` but to count them as you replace them.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems a little bit longer than I expected. But it give me a great deal of instructions in Fortran!

Comment: Show your gratitude by upvoting, even accepting, the answer.